# Reactjs how to import constant array from another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

In my app, I have a huge constant array of string defined in allCurrency.js file as follows. The real array is much longer than the given array. I import it in my App.js file as `import currecyData from './allCurrency'`. There is no syntax error. I can't access it in App.js. Just a warning  import currecyData from './allCurrency'. How do I access in App.js. I don't want to bring the whole constant array in App.js. It will work, but it will be ugly.

```
const currecyData = [
    "AED",
    "ARS",
    "AUD",
    "BGN",
    "BRL",
    "BSD",
    "CAD",
    "CHF",
    "CLP",
    "CNY",
    "COP",
    "CZK",
    "DKK",
    "DOP",
    "EGP",
    "EUR",
    "FJD",
    "GBP"]
```

Comment: did you do `export default currecyData` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const currecyData = [
"AED",
"ARS",
"AUD",
"BGN",
"BRL",
"BSD",
"CAD",
"CHF",
"CLP",
"CNY",
"COP",
"CZK",
"DKK",
"DOP",
"EGP",
"EUR",
"FJD",
"GBP"];export default currecyData;
```

You have to export the entity to import it.

Answer (score 1):

Either do an

```
export const currecyData = [
    "AED",
    "ARS",
    "AUD",
    "BGN",
    "BRL",
    "BSD",
    "CAD",
    "CHF",
    "CLP",
    "CNY",
    "COP",
    "CZK",
    "DKK",
    "DOP",
    "EGP",
    "EUR",
    "FJD",
    "GBP"]
```

And import it as

```
import {currecyData} from './allCurrency'
```

or add a default export in your allCurrency.js as obiwankenoobi commented:

```
export default currecyData;
```